Encryption is not happening for the null values in bigquery
Encryption is not happening for the null values in bigquery. How to handle this? I am using TO_HEX(AEAD.ENCRYPT(keyset, CAST(null AS string), AeadData)) AS Enc_value. I am getting null in the result. Can someone please help?

The documentation states that AEAD.Encrypt will return null if any input is null, so you'll need to check your input for null and use another value instead, perhaps an empty string or a sentinel like "!!!!NULL!!!!".  Then have whatever is decrypting the values know to check for the sentinel.
